# How to interpret arrow pointing away from function declaration?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, machine-learning

[image: Screenshot]

How should I interpret the above?
I can see that succs is what this function is being named and that in the second line we have an example of it's use. I can also see that Q, which is predefined as a *finite set of states*, and the powerset of Q have some stake in this operation but I just can't work out what.

Any thoughts? Is this common notation and am I missing something obvious or have I just asked a very narrow question with niche notation?

Comment: It is the common way to represent [math functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)). Function $\text {succs}$ is a function that associates to every *state* $s \in Q$ a set of states, i.e. a subset of $Q$, that is the set of the states "reachable" from $s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that "succs" is a function whose domain is $Q$--that is, $Q$ is the set of allowable inputs--and whose codomain is the power set of $Q$--that is, every output will be a subset of $Q$.

The second line tells how to determine the output, given any input.

Comment: This has cleared things up nicely,  thank you

Comment: You're very welcome!